# Error:(7, 0) Cannot change dependencies of configuration ':barcodescanner:classpath' after it has been resolved

Tags: android, android-studio, zxing, barcode-scanner

[image]

Hi all developers. 
I'm currently developing an android native app. In my project, I used Zxing barcodescanner module to apply qrcode feature in my app. Now I want it being updated to the latest dependency. I've already updated dependency by change from this

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.14.0'
    }
}
```

into these one

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2'
    }
}
```

According to GitHub repo of barcodescanner I used to. But it seem an error is a rise. it cant change configuration after it has been resolved. Any suggestion to solve the error? Thank you in advance.

the github repo I used the barcodescanner is stated below link 
https://github.com/dm77/barcodescanner

Comment: which android Studio version you can use ?

Comment: currently i use android studio version 3.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`build.gradle(ProjectName):` in this build u can add below line :

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
```

`build.gradle(Module:app):` in this build u can add below `Zxing` library:

```
compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.8'
```

Change your Code like below code:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    }
}
```

try make sure it's a useful for you:

Comment: thank you i will updated for it if it solved for me. Thank you again.

Comment: this is the right solution then put as a right answer  and this is not right solution then u can update my answer and right answer to this becoz other user have same error then this useful for everyone so

Comment: alright for right moment i considering your answer is useful i will updated once it solved. thanks again @ Mohammad Ali

Comment: your solution is work thank you for the solution. thumb up

Comment: im the new user so stackoverflow prevent me put up voter.